# Как вызвать массив из первого метода во втором методе?

Tags: java, массивы

```java
public class Hospital {
    public static float[] generatePatientsTemperatures(int patientsCount) {
        float[] people = new float[patientsCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
            people[i] = (float) (32.0 + 8 * Math.random());
            //System.out.println(people[i]);
            //people[i] = (float) temp;
        }
        return people;
    }

    public static String getReport(float[] temperatureData) {
        String report = "Температуры пациентов: " + 0 +
                "\nСредняя температура: " + 0 +
                "\nКоличество здоровых: " + 0;

        return report;
    }
}
```

Comment: Массив внутри класса можно сделать доступным для нескольких методов этого класса.

Answer (score 0):

Массив нельзя вызвать, вызывать можно только методы.

Возможно, что-то такое нужно написать:

```
float[] temps = Hospital.generatePatientsTemperatures(...);
String report = Hospital.getReport(temps);
```